# Zooming to a particular area in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to implement an application in which it will load an image and zoom to a face if there is any when a button is clicked. I have used the face detection APIs for the detection part and retrieved the midpoint of a face. Now, the problem that I am facing is zooming to the area around the face. I am using a custom Imageview to display the image.
Couldn't find anything much useful in previous SO questions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get the pixels of that part of the image(that are showing the face) and make another image only with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Mike Ortiz's [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java), pay attention to the DoubleTapZoom, that's the class which is going to be used. You may write your own class extending TouchImageView which supports zoom to face, something like this:

```
private void zoomToFace (float faceX, float faceY) {
    DoubleTapZoom zoom = new DoubleTapZoom(targetZoom, faceX, faceY, false);
    postDelayed(zoom, 1000/60);
}
```